# Crashing when embedding iframe in webview IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iframe, uiwebview

Crash log

```
11  UIKit                               0x01ee6c7d -[UIWebView webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:] + 323
12  UIKit                               0x01ee92f9 -[UIWebViewWebViewDelegate webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:] + 80
13  CoreFoundation                      0x0356a10d __invoking___ + 29
14  CoreFoundation                      0x03569fb8 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 360
15  CoreFoundation                      0x03601b7a -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 74
16  WebKitLegacy                        0x09870d20 -[_WebSafeForwarder forwardInvocation:] + 160
17  CoreFoundation                      0x035d798e ___forwarding___ + 478
18  CoreFoundation                      0x035d778e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
19  CoreFoundation                      0x0356a10d __invoking___ + 29
20  CoreFoundation                      0x03569fb8 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 360
21  WebCore                             0x0a990226 _ZL20HandleDelegateSourcePv + 118
22  CoreFoundation                      0x035aa98f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
23  CoreFoundation                      0x035a049d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253
24  CoreFoundation                      0x0359f9f8 __CFRunLoopRun + 952
25  CoreFoundation                      0x0359f37b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
26  CoreFoundation                      0x0359f1ab CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
27  GraphicsServices                    0x057282c1 GSEventRunModal + 192
28  GraphicsServices                    0x057280fe GSEventRun + 104
29  UIKit                               0x01c1f9b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
30  iSlideshow                          0x004ffbad main + 141
31  libdyld.dylib                       0x047deac9 start + 1
```

I get this crash log when i try to embed iframe in a webview.
Function that i use to embed the iframe
Right now embedding a text, it crashes after the text appears
For iframe, the videos dont appear and it crashes.

```
-(void)handleExternalWebsite: (NSString*)embed :(UIView*)container
{
NSLog(@"embed --- %@", embed);

NSString *textValue= @"asdasdkasgdhjasgd";

webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:container.bounds];
[webview loadHTMLString:textValue baseURL:nil];
[container addSubview:webview];
}
-(void)dealloc{

if (webview.delegate == self)
{
    webview.delegate = nil;
    [webview stopLoading];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To debug these kind of crashes, add the exception breakpoint as below:-

1. Go to the breakpoint navigator.
2. Click on + button (lower left corner).
3. Click on first option i.e Add exception breakpoint.

Now run your project. Now when there is a crash, the exception breakpoint will tell you where the code is breaking.

[image]

Comment: No this doesnt help in this case, I have also used NSZombies thats also isnt helping